# How can I replicate the Excel FV function in PHP?

Tags: php, excel

I'm converting some rather complex calculations from an Excel spreadsheet, to PHP. I'm stuck on the conversion of Excel's FV function, which is defined thusly:

```
FV( interest_rate, number_payments, payment, PV, Type )
```

I've been working on this for 2 hours now, and there has to be something I'm missing. Essentially, I need to replicate this functionality into an equivalent PHP function, taking all of the aforementioned arguments.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Slightly modified from the PHPExcel function library:

```
/**
 * FV
 *
 * Returns the Future Value of a cash flow with constant payments and interest rate (annuities).
 *
 * @param   float   $rate   Interest rate per period
 * @param   int     $nper   Number of periods
 * @param   float   $pmt    Periodic payment (annuity)
 * @param   float   $pv     Present Value
 * @param   int     $type   Payment type: 0 = at the end of each period, 1 = at the beginning of each period
 * @return  float
 */
function FV($rate = 0, $nper = 0, $pmt = 0, $pv = 0, $type = 0) {

    // Validate parameters
    if ($type != 0 && $type != 1) {
        return False;
    }

    // Calculate
    if ($rate != 0.0) {
        return -$pv * pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - $pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * (pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - 1) / $rate;
    } else {
        return -$pv - $pmt * $nper;
    }
}   //  function FV()


echo FV(0.0149562574418, 4, 43.875, -250);
```

returns 85.818510876629

// Unit test

```
class ExcelTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function test_it_calculates_fv_value()
    {
        $test_data = [
            [ 0.005,          10, -200,  -500,    1,    2581.4033740601 ],
            [ 0.01,           12, -1000, null,    null, 12682.503013197 ],
            [ 0.009166666667, 35, -2000, null,    1,    82846.246372418 ],
            [ 0.005,          12, -100,  -1000,   1,    2301.4018303409 ],
            [ 0.004166666667, 60, -1000, null,    null, 68006.082841536 ],
            [ 0.025,          16, -2000, 0,       1,    39729.460894166 ],
            [ 0.0,            12, -100,  -100,    null, 1300            ]
        ];

        $test_case_id = 0;
        foreach($test_data as $test_case) {
            $test_case_id++;
            list($rate, $nper, $pmt, $pv, $type, $expected_result) = $test_case;
            $this->assertEquals($expected_result, Excel::FV($rate, $nper, $pmt, $pv, $type), "Test case $test_case_id failed", 0.0000001);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function fv($r,$n,$p,$pv=0)
{
   $sum = $pv;
   for ( $i=0;$i<$n;$i++ )
   {
       $sum += $sum*$r + $p;
   }
   return $sum;
}

echo fv(0.1,4,10,100);
```

The extension of the `Type` parameter is left as an excercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I am not getting the answer I'm supposed to be getting from this function.

My param values are as follows, in correct order:

0.0149562574418,
4,
43.875,
-250

- The value I am supposed to be getting back (as I am from the Excel document), is 85.82 - any ideas? :S

Comment: Does not seem to be working, I need help converting the following excel formula PV(.0588/12,300,868.0583333) the output i am expecting is 136,275.88, but the output that i am getting is 590573.166. I have spent hours but i cant seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the modified function of the MathPHP library.

```
<?php
/**
 * Future value for a loan or annuity with compound interest.
 *
 * Same as the =FV() function in most spreadsheet software.
 *
 * The basic future-value formula derivation:
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_value
 *
 *                   PMT*((1+r)ᴺ - 1)
 * FV = -PV*(1+r)ᴺ - ----------------
 *                          r
 *
 * The (1+r*when) factor adjusts the payment to the beginning or end
 * of the period. In the common case of a payment at the end of a period,
 * the factor is 1 and reduces to the formula above. Setting when=1 computes
 * an "annuity due" with an immediate payment.
 *
 * Examples:
 * The future value in 5 years on a 30-year fixed mortgage note of $265000
 * at 3.5% interest paid at the end of every month. This is how much loan
 * principle would be outstanding:
 *   fv(0.035/12, 5*12, 1189.97, -265000, false)
 *
 * The present_value is negative indicating money borrowed for the mortgage,
 * whereas payment is positive, indicating money that will be paid to the
 * mortgage.
 *
 * @param float $rate
 * @param int $periods
 * @param float $payment
 * @param float $present_value
 * @param bool $beginning adjust the payment to the beginning or end of the period
 *
 * @return float
 */
function fv(float $rate, int $periods, float $payment, float $present_value, bool $beginning = false)
{
    $when = $beginning ? 1 : 0;

    if ($rate == 0) {
        $fv = -($present_value + ($payment * $periods));
        return $fv;
    }

    $initial = 1 + ($rate * $when);
    $compound = pow(1 + $rate, $periods);
    $fv = -(($present_value * $compound) + (($payment * $initial * ($compound - 1)) / $rate));

    return $fv;
}
```

It worked very well, I hope it helps.

Reference: https://github.com/markrogoyski/math-php/blob/master/src/Finance.php

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue and got help from someone on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073169/need-help-converting-pv-formula-to-php) post,  I hope someone else finds it helpful too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this really nice function. These two above did not work for my needs...

$R for the rate, $n number of period, $pmt is the amount paid

> function PV($R,$n,$pmt,$m=1) {
>
> $Z = 1 / (1 + ($R/$m));
>
> return ($pmt * $Z * (1 - pow($Z,$n)))/(1 - $Z);
>
> }

```
echo PV(0,00333333, 180, 1221);
```

Don't forget, if want to know for example how much you will get after 15 years if you pay in 1221€ per month with an annual rate of 4%, you will have to divide per 12 the rate and put 180 months.