# Need help converting PV formula to PHP

Tags: php, excel-formula

I need help converting the following excel formula to PHP

`PV(.0588/12,300,868.0583333)`

The output I am expecting is `136,275.88`, but the output that I am getting is `590573.166`. I have spent hours on it but I can't seem to find the solution.

This is my code

```
function FV($rate = 0, $nper = 0, $pmt = 0, $pv =0, $type = 0)
{

    // Validate parameters
    if ($type != 0 && $type != 1) {
        return False;
    }

    // Calculate
    if ($rate != 0.0) {
        return -$pv * pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - $pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * (pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - 1) / $rate;
    } else {
        return -$pv - $pmt * $nper;
    }
} //  function FV()
echo FV(.0588/12, 300, -868.06);
```

I have gone through the [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321228/how-can-i-replicate-the-excel-fv-function-in-php) post before but that does not solve.

I have also gone through the PHP [site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php#50833) but that does not help either.

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks, but isn't `fv` optional? if not how do i calculate the `fv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is for `FV`, but apparently you want it for `PV`. You're in luck as Alejandro Pedraza already made a [**PEAR package `Math_Finance`**](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Finance) for this. Here's the function extracted to prove that it works (***you should include the full `Finance.php` with its copyright info in your project!***).

```
<?php
    /**
    * Extracted from the PEAR package Math_Finance by Alejandro Pedraza
    * http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Finance
    *
    * Returns the Present Value of a cash flow with constant payments and interest rate (annuities)
    * Excel equivalent: PV
    *
    *   TVM functions solve for a term in the following formula:
    *   pv(1+r)^n + pmt(1+r.type)((1+r)^n - 1)/r) +fv = 0
    *
    *
    * @param float      Interest rate per period 
    * @param int        Number of periods
    * @param float      Periodic payment (annuity)
    * @param float      Future Value
    * @param int        Payment type:
                            FINANCE_PAY_END (default):    at the end of each period
                            FINANCE_PAY_BEGIN:            at the beginning of each period
    * @return float     
    * @static
    * @access public
    */
    function presentValue($rate, $nper, $pmt, $fv = 0, $type = 0)
    {
        if ($nper < 0) {
            return PEAR::raiseError('Number of periods must be positive');
        }
        if ($type != FINANCE_PAY_END && $type != FINANCE_PAY_BEGIN) {
            return PEAR::raiseError('Payment type must be FINANCE_PAY_END or FINANCE_PAY_BEGIN');
        }

        if ($rate) {
            $pv = (-$pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * ((pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - 1) / $rate) - $fv) / pow(1 + $rate, $nper);
        } else {
            $pv = -$fv - $pmt * $nper;
        }
        return $pv;
    }
?>
```

**Usage**:

```
<?php   
    var_dump( presentValue(.0588/12,300,868.0583333) );
    // float(-136275.88429118)
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/JB0hn5cu)

**Note**:

Like previously mentioned, you should use the full [`Finance.php`](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Finance) file from the PEAR page in order for this to work perfectly (as you might get notices of undefined constants, and it can't raise errors). You can find the package [**HERE**](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Finance).

[Finance.php on github](https://github.com/pear/Math_Finance/blob/master/Math/Finance.php)

Comment: Thank you so much @h2ooooooo, spent hours on trying to solve this.