# Function Excel to php

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have the function

```
=VF(M45,M46,M47)
```

is it posible to convert the function to be used in PHP

I have tried

```
=(A1*(1+A1)^B1)*C1/(((1+A1)^B1)-1)
```

but it does not give the same result

Comment: It just does some maths, so there should be no reason you can't implement it in any programming language. The problem might be finding out the details of what calculations the function carries out internally, although I suspect it's not particularly complex and you could work it out based on the [documentation and examples](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fv-function-2eef9f44-a084-4c61-bdd8-4fe4bb1b71b3). You shown us some sort of attempt in Excel - I guess to re-implement the formula? But it's not clear what the relevance of that is, since you state you want to re-implement in PHP.

Comment: What is this for `^`?  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php   https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php

Comment: Also, maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321228/how-can-i-replicate-the-excel-fv-function-in-php